# Running an old 32bit application on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, 32-bit

We currently have an ancient (1995) 32-bit application that we have to run called Muscat. (There is no source code - this was a commercial application.)

It works on Ubuntu 18.04, though I cannot yet get it working on 20.04. As a result we have been running an 18.04 VM but that is going out of support soon and I would like to do this properly. We are currently stuck with this system due to a large amount of data but there is a lot of curation work required to migrate, which we have limited funding for.

I'm aware of the i386 changes that were [announced](https://canonical.com/blog/statement-on-32-bit-i386-packages-for-ubuntu-19-10-and-20-04-lts), but this whole area of Linux is fairly unfamiliar to me.

The application executable is called `fx.sp`.

We run it as a wrapper script containing:

`/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./fx.sp`

Running this on 20.04 gives:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 fx.sp
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't really know how to go further, though my assumption here, given that it did work previously, is that either a library is not present or a function call is pointing into some bit of a 32bit subsystem that is now missing.

I found that ldd is used to see the dependencies, and that gives the following:

```
ldd /lib/ld-linux.so.2 fx.sp
/lib/ld-linux.so.2:
    statically linked
fx.sp:
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f6f000)
    libdl.so.1 => /lib/libdl.so.1 (0xf7f4c000)
    libc.so.5 => /lib/libc.so.5 (0xf7e83000)
```

The three mentioned libraries are all present, symlinked to the central copy of the original library files we have kept from year-to-year as machines have been upgraded:

```
ls -lAF /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /lib/libdl.so.1 /lib/libc.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Apr  7  2022 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Jan 27  2015 /lib/libc.so.5 -> /software/muscat/libraries/libc.so.5.3.12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Jan 27  2015 /lib/libdl.so.1 -> /software/muscat/libraries/libdl.so.1.7.14
```

I understand that linux-gate.so.1 is a virtual representation in the kernel so is not present.

We do also have the i386 architecture installed as follows:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install libc6:i386
```

I've got a core dump created, which gives:

```
gdb fx.sp /var/lib/apport/coredump/core...
...
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xf7f3c686 in __libc_init () from /lib/libc.so.5
```

That `/lib/libc.so.5` file is one of the original libraries that we have kept for 20 years.

Running strace without the wrapper, I get:

On the **working 18.04** machine:

```
$ strace -o strace.webmuscat1804 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./fx.sp
execve("/lib/ld-linux.so.2", ["/lib/ld-linux.so.2", "./fx.sp"], 0x7ffe3d4d3ef8 /* 25 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x56bdb000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./fx.sp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\0\224\4\0104\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=1431032, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/path/to/cgi-bin-private", 128) = 59
mmap2(0x8048000, 811008, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x8048000
mmap2(0x810e000, 483328, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc5000) = 0x810e000
mmap2(0x8184000, 210672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x8184000
mprotect(0xffe59000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC|PROT_GROWSDOWN) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7f7f000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=64923, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 64923, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xf7f3e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libdl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0@\7\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6875, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8504, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7f36000
mmap2(0xf7f38000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xf7f38000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libc.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0(k\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=699832, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 820372, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7e66000
mmap2(0xf7ef7000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x90000) = 0xf7ef7000
mmap2(0xf7efd000, 201876, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7efd000
close(3)                                = 0
set_thread_area({entry_number=-1, base_addr=0xf7f7ff40, limit=0x0fffff, seg_32bit=1, contents=0, read_exec_only=0, limit_in_pages=1, seg_not_present=0, useable=1}) = 0 (entry_number=12)
munmap(0xf7f3e000, 64923)               = 0
personality(PER_LINUX)                  = 0 (PER_LINUX)
geteuid()                               = 1001
getuid()                                = 1001
getgid()                                = 1001
getegid()                               = 1001
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7f7e000
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(1, "FX 1.4 24/02/1998 (Actually comp"..., 59) = 59
write(1, "Options: LOGGING UNIX COMPILED ("..., 42) = 42
write(1, "Enter NAME=VALUE lines, end with"..., 44) = 44
write(1, "Content-type: text/html\n\n", 25) = 25
brk(NULL)                               = 0x56bdb000
brk(0x56bdb068)                         = 0x56bdb068
brk(0x56bdc000)                         = 0x56bdc000
open("/etc/muscat-fx.cf", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=35, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7f50000
read(3, "/usr/local/MuscatFX/src/muscat 8"..., 4096) = 35
lseek(3, -1, SEEK_CUR)                  = 34
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xf7f50000, 4096)                = 0
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7f50000
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
read(0, 0xf7f50000, 1024)               = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

and on the **non-working 20.04** machine:

```
execve("/lib/ld-linux.so.2", ["/lib/ld-linux.so.2", "./fx.sp"], 0x7ffce2848dc8 /* 26 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x58335000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0xff8f1038) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./fx.sp", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\0\224\4\0104\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512*emphasized text*
getcwd("/path/to/cgi-bin-private", 128) = 45
mmap2(0x8048000, 811008, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x8048000
mmap2(0x810e000, 483328, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc5000) = 0x810e000
mmap2(0x8184000, 210672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x8184000
mprotect(0xff8f1000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC|PROT_GROWSDOWN) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7ef2000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=107716, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 107716, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xf7ed7000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libdl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0@\7\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6875, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8504, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7ed4000
mmap2(0xf7ed6000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xf7ed6000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libc.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0(k\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=699832, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 820372, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7e0b000
mmap2(0xf7e9c000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x90000) = 0xf7e9c000
mmap2(0xf7ea2000, 201876, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7ea2000
close(3)                                = 0
set_thread_area({entry_number=-1, base_addr=0xf7ef2fc0, limit=0x0fffff, seg_32bit=1, contents=0, read_exec_only=0, limit_in_pages=1, seg_not_present=0, useable=1}) = 0 (entry_number=12)
munmap(0xf7ed7000, 107716)              = 0
personality(PER_LINUX)                  = 0 (PER_LINUX)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x95da8} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

This is far as I have got.

PS Ultimately I would like to containerise the setup, and if anyone can give some good advice on that, that would also be helpful.

Comment: Install Ubuntu 18.04 in VM.

Comment: @Toto I've clarified that's what we're temporarily doing, but it goes out of support soon.

Comment: @fooquency If you truly want to do this properly, use recent software which is able to run on 64bit systems.

Comment: @mashuptwice I've clarified that work is being done to deal with data migration but this is a time-consuming and costly process. Within a few years hopefully it will be done.

Comment: Work-Arounds & Debugging Possibilities [[[[ (1) On the working machine , run the `ldd` command & get the versions listed ; then try to copy that over to the non-working machine & make the Sym-links Point to those (2) If you have the Source Code , try to Compile it on the target machines (3) Check & try to get older versions of the library Binaries (4) Try running `strace` & `lstrace` to check where it is crashing. (5) Try to generate the core file ( enable core dumping in your shell ) ; then get a back-trace to check where it is crashing (6) Ensure that the library Binaries are 32-bit ]]]]

Comment: @Prem: Thanks. On (5) I've done `gdb fx.sp /var/lib/apport/coredump/core...` and it's giving `Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. #0  0xf7f3c686 in __libc_init () from /lib/libc.so.5`. That is one of the original files, so I'm not sure why a call into that would be an issue.

Comment: you could try running it under truss, see if that tells you anything useful.

Comment: @Robert Longson. Ah, running it under `strace` gives `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` on the line before the segfault line. There are also lines before that complaining about `/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo`. So possibly a locale issue?

Comment: quite possibly, at least you've something to go on now. Good luck.

Comment: For information Ubuntu 18.04 normal support ends in 2023, but the extended support is available until 2028. The extended support is free for personal use, and a paid option otherwise. https://ubuntu.com/security/esm

Comment: Setting things like LANG=EN etc doesn't seem to make a difference. Main question I have really is whether Ubuntu 20.04 should fundamentally be able to run this or whether there is some kind of significant change that would prevent a 32bit app running.

Comment: [ (2) I think you have no Source Code ] [ (1) & (3) , were you able to copy over the working library Binaries to non-working machine ? ] [ (6) I think you have verified 32-bit library Binaries ] [ (5) , crash is inside `__libc_init ()` maybe because it is trying to access variables which have mismatching new locations in new versions ; Will be good to execute `bt` command inside `gdb` to generate backtrace ] [ (4) , `strace` is reporting completion of `openat ()` on the missing file , hence it is not the Issue : We should compare with working machine `strace` to check what should occur next ]

Comment: @Prem: Thanks so much again for these pointers. Yes, the new installation has the same binaries/libraries copied over. I've added above the two backtraces from the working 18.04 and the non-working 20.04. I'll see if I can work out how to use `bt`. This is all a bit beyond my knowledge but I can see where this is going. Is it possible there is a different C (or other dependent) library and copying over an old one and forcing the exe to use the local path is an issue here?

Comment: I will consolidate all my thoughts in a Post.

Comment: Were you able to look into why the "wrapper script" was Different in the two machines ? Were you able to check which UserID was which [ in 501 & 1001 ] ? When `strace` runs on "wrapper script" , we will not get the `strace` output of the actual Muscat Binary , which is a Separate Process. If you can check the "wrapper script" , you might change the line to `strace Muscat` to get that output too.

Comment: @Prem - Yes, am about to repost the traces, as I realised they were inconsistent. Thanks so much for following up!

Comment: @Prem I've now updated both strace results. The wrapper file is now identical (as confirmed with an md5sum check). The wrapper file just runs `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./fx.sp` though there are comments in the file. If I try running `strace ./fx.sp` I get almost no output at all.

Comment: The Command should be `strace /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./fx.sp` in that Case. The user running that should Ideally be the same : UserID 501 versus UserID 1001 has a concern about the Home Directory & Potential Config files inside that Home Directory

Comment: OK, I've now updated to that. The home directories have no relevant config files in, as we avoid ever using those for running stuff not related to an individual user.

Comment: Updated the Answer with my latest findings & Conclusions.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Unfortunately we don't have the source code. But I've learnt a lot on this. I'm now looking at an alternative strategy on how to get the data out, as it seems clear the software is unlikely to run. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I containerised the application using Docker with an 18.04 image.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid long unreadable comments, I am putting it all in this Answer Box. I will consolidate it all , a while later.

I have gone through into the two `strace` outputs & have some quick observations.

(7) In Working Case & In Non-Working Case , we are using /path/to/wrapper.fx.sp , but the contents seem to be Different ?

Working Case :

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/wrapper.fx.sp", O_RDONLY) = 3  
read(3, "#!/bin/bash\n/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /"..., 80) = 80
```

The Script starts like this :

```
#!/bin/bash  
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /
```

Non-Working Case :

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/wrapper.fx.sp", O_RDONLY) = 3  
read(3, "#!/bin/bash\n\n#ulimit -S -c unlim"..., 80) = 80
```

The Script now starts like this :

```
#!/bin/bash  
#ulimit -S -c unlim
```

(8) More-over , that is only a "wrapper" shell script. We might have to look into that to check what Binary it will eventually run (Eg /bin/MUSCAT) & then execute `ldd /bin/MUSCAT` to gather more Debug Points eg to know what is missing or what library version is mismatching.

(9) In Working Case , we have UserID 1001 which uses Directory "/home/myusername" :

```
getuid()                                = 1001  
"/home/myusername"
```

Where-as, In Working Case , we have UserID 501 & Directory "/home/myusername" is not used ( it is using the Default Current Directory ) :

```
getuid()                                = 501  
"/path/to..."
```

Can we check whether we can make the Same User & Same Directory ( with maybe Same Configuration like ~/.muscat.conf ) available on Non-Working Case ?
The intention is to eliminate some Hardcoded Paths in the Binary.

We are trying to Debug the Issue.
We may eventually be able to figure out the Exact Change in Configuration which is making it crash. Whether we can fix or or not is a Different Issue !

LATEST UPDATE:

Checking `strace /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./fx.sp` :

Here , the Working Case executes `mmap2()` on "820372+24576+201876 Bytes"
& then `munmap()` on **"64923 Bytes"**
& then `personality(PER_LINUX)`
& then moves on to UID functions `geteuid()` & `getuid()`

Where-as the Non-Working Case executes `mmap2()` on "820372+24576+201876 Bytes" (SAME)
& then `munmap` on **"107716 Bytes"** (MORE !!!!)
& then lastly executes `personality(PER_LINUX)`
& not making it to UID functions.

CONCLUSIONS :

(UNLIKELY POSSIBLITY 1) Maybe PER_LINUX is no longer supported in Ubuntu 20.04 & PER_LINUX32 is necessary
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html

(MORE LIKELY POSSIBLITY 2) There is a CODE BUG in `webmuscat` which is wrongly unmapping more memory & then accessing the unmapped memory , which will generate the SIGSEGV !
https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap2 & https://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap
Here is the Crucial Part :

`The munmap() system call deletes the mappings for the specified address range, and causes further references to addresses within the range to generate invalid memory references`

`subsequent references to these pages will generate SIGSEGV`

In this Case , we have to look into the C Source to fix the Bug which is getting triggered in weird way.